# Adding two integers with a "+" or "-" string

Tags: parameters, integer, calculator, addition, subtraction

I have a pocket calculator assignment in my CS Python class and I need to take a string "+" or "-" as a parameter, and use it to add two numbers. How do I add two integers with a "+" or "-" parameter by changing it from a string?

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I am not the most experienced python user but I think you can try this.

```
num1 = float(input('Enter your First #: '))
op = input('Enter Op + or -: ')
num2 = float(input('Enter your Second#: '))

if op == "+":
    print(num1 +num2)
elif op == "-":
    print(num1 - num2)
else:
    print("Invalid op")
```

just to add a little confused about your question.